# How can I get up-to-date environment variable values when my console app starts up?

Tags: .net-core, configuration, environment-variables

I have a .NET Core command-line app (netcoreapp3.1) and I am configuring it using environment variables:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables("myapp_")
    .Build();
```

When the program is run from the command line, the environment variable values are those that existed when the command line window was opened. If I run the program under the debugger from Visual Studio, then the environment variable values are those that existed when that instance of Visual Studio started.

This isn't acceptable, because I am forgetful and because it is onerous to restart these things when I want to change the value of a configuration setting. How can I get the up-to-date values at the time my program starts (not the values that were in place when whatever "thing" is running my program was itself started)?

Comment: That's simply not possible, pretty much due to how environment variables are designed. They are only passed from a parent process to a child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** possible to use the while-runtime-changed environment variables in the `IConfiguration` constuct.
The configuration is read one time while the host startup:
[Resource on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/d469707ab18eef7ed0002f00175a9ad5b0f36250/src/Config.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs)

But you can use a file instead. Just change the file content instead of environment variables. The console app can react on these file changes and use the new parameters.

#### Example with `appsettings.json` changes while runtime

```
        var i = 0;
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            i++;

            // _options is of type: IOptionsMonitor<Settings>
            _logger.LogInformation(_options.CurrentValue.Test);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), token);
            
            if(i == 2)
            {
                // just for demo purpose change the appsettings.json file
                // on the fly to display the new config settings
                _logger.LogWarning("Change 'Test' = 2");
                File.WriteAllText("appsettings.json", "{\"Test\": \"2\"}");
            }
            
            if(i > 5)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

[Full example on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GsjbOh)

#### Usage of `IOptionsMonitor<T>`

With the configured `appsettings.json` file and `reloadOnChange: true` an `IOptionsMonitor<T>` can be used to always get the current value of the configuration.

```
return new HostBuilder()
        .UseEnvironment("BETA")
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true))
        .ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole())
        .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
                               services.AddOptions()
                                       .Configure<Settings>(ctx.Configuration)
                                       .AddHostedService<TestHost>());
```

[For completeness the IOptionsMonitor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)